# Grouping child elements in smaller sub-groups based on text in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Update: Solved it by using .wrapAll

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".filterformbox:contains('Approved Selection')" ).wrapAll( "<div class='new' />");
});
```

I have an container with a bunch of divs. These divs has text in them, and I want to group the divs with similar text inside them inside their own sub-group with their own class.

This is the html:

```
   <div class="column wide">
   <div class="filterformbox">
   <label>  
   <a class="checkboxOn" href="/products/Computers/Desktops?hpcs=59">A3&nbsp;Approved Selection Budget  
  </label></div>
  <div class="filterformbox">
  <label>  
   <a class="checkboxOn" href="/products/Computers/Desktops?hpcs=59">A3&nbsp;Approved Selection ONE
  </label></div>
  <div class="filterformbox"></div>
  <div class="filterformbox"></div>
  <div class="filterformbox"></div>
  <div class="filterformbox"></div>
  </div>
```

The divs are grouped in three and twos- in the example the first group all have "Approved Selection" in the three first divs, then theere a group of other divs with other strings in them.

I was playing around with jquery to set a class in the individual divs, and that worked great. But how do I group them together?

The script I used for setting the class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".filterformbox:contains('Approved Selection')" ).addClass( "apfilter" );
});
```

Comment: Please provide more info and link to jsfiddle with what ever you have tried.

Comment: Your `Approved Selection` `label` is not the child for `filterformbox` `div` as i can see form your **HTML**

Comment: The info of what I tried is right there. What I tried obviously doesn't work for more then setting an individual class on the divs - So setting up an fiddle with that seemed unnecessary. Other then that Im not sure what to try - hence the question.

Comment: Your correct, I wrote the HTML wrong. updated it now. Thanks! @KawineshSK

Comment: what is the outcome you want to achieve?